# Permission for release def security editing in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, ms-release-management

TFS 2015 R2. I have a release definition. I'm trying to disallow editing of it to collection administrators (only *server* administrators can edit). Here's the current setup:

- Permission inheritance - Off
- Administer release permissions, Edit release definition, Edit release environment - `Not set` for all groups except server admins, `Allow` for server admins

The collection admins indeed can't edit the def in question, **but they can change the security on it**, letting themselves edit again. Any way to disallow permission editing? Seems like none of the release def permissions covers editing permissions themselves.

Setting Deny for coll admins and Allow for server admins doesn't work, since the latter group belongs to the former; even as you set Allow, when you try to save, it switched to "Inherited deny".

EDIT: take 2, changed Administer release permissions, Edit release definition to Deny for all groups with Allow for myself. The coll admin can still mess with permissions.

UPDATE: reported that to Microsoft, if you're experiencing this too, [click here and upvote](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/60553/unable-to-secure-a-release-definition-from-collect.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update2**

Even though a TFS server admin could do anything in TFS server, however **not all TFS permissions be defined in TFS Server group**. This is why Team Foundation Administrators group be added in Project Collection Administrators group by default.

[image]

So your permission in the collection (even though you are a TFS server admin) is also granted from project collection administrator group. How does a windows admin to disallow another windows admin? It's the same concept. So you may have to either orallyinformed  them or move them out of the project collection admin group. Add the users in another group.

---

**Update**

It's able to directly deny the collection admins to edit the release definition. However, it's not able to disallow them to edit the permission back themselves. Members of the team project collection group can perform all privileged operations on the Team Project Collection.

Besides, there is no such related permission to disallow someone in the team project collection group to edit the release definition permission. Seems we can only  through the notice restrict they modifying the set permissions on the release definition.

---

In TFS **deny trumps allow**. You could add all your collection administrators  to a particular group. Then you just need to disable this particular group permission to edit the release definition.

After changing the **Edit release definition** to **Deny** for project collection Administrators group.
[image]
It's not able to modify the release definition for me which in the project collection Administrator group now. The adding task is grayed.

[image]

Comment: For the life of me, it doesn't work that way. "Deny" for "Administer release permissions" for all lines except one, and yet the test collection admin can edit them. Have you tried reproducing?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev You just need to change the Edit release definition to Deny. It works on my side. Please see my update reply

Comment: I did that too. Question for your setup - can a project admin go to the release def's Security screen and **allow Edit for themselves**? They can in mine.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Sorry for the misunderstanding,finally got your point.  When you open the Collection > Project Collection Administrators in server security page you will get `Administrator group cannot be modified.`  Members of this application group can perform all privileged operations on the Team Project Collection. You could not able to disallow  permission editing for users in team project collection to use the **security**. There is no such related permission. There is only a Manipulate security settings permission for folders in server level. Not able only for a release definition.

Comment: So there's simply no way to lock a release def from collection admins. Is this behavior the same in TFS 2017?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev It's able to directly deny the collection admins to edit the release definition. However, it's not able to disallow them to edit the permission back themselves. You could argue that  from this point.  Seems we can only  orallyinformed them modifying the set permissions on the release definition.

Comment: What's the point of denying someone a permission when they can modify permissions anytime :) The question is - is this by design or a bug?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev I'm afraid this is by design. Even though a TFS server admin could do anything in TFS server, however not all TFS permissions be defined in TFS Server group.  This is why Team Foundation Administrators group be added in Project Collection Administrators group by default. So your permission (even though you are a TFS server admin) is also granted from project collection administrator group. How does a windows admin to disallow another windows admin? It's the same concept. So you may have to either  orallyinformed  them or move them out of the project collection admin group.

Comment: The Windows admin analogy is somewhat flawed - a domain admin can very much restrict local admins via group policy :) Any change of this behavior in TFS 2017, please?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Afraid not. Tested, got the same behavior in TFS2017.

Answer (score 1):

Project Collection Administrators is a built-in-collection-level group which has permissions to **perform all operations for the account or collection**. So it is an expected behavior that the members in this group can change any settings in this collection. The workaround is creating a new group with the permission you'd like to assign and moving some members from Collection Administrators to this new group since the Collection Administrators Group should be restricted to the smallest possible number of users who need total administrative control over the collection.

> Project Collection Administrators ▼
>
> Permission: Has permissions to perform all operations for the account or collection.
>
> Membership: Contains the Local Administrators group
> (BUILTIN\Administrators) for the server where the application-tier
> services for TFS have been installed. Also, contains the members of
> the CollectionName\Service Accounts group.
>
> This group should be restricted to the smallest possible number of
> users who need total administrative control over the collection.

Refer to this link for details: [Permissions and groups defined for Team Services and TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/permissions).

Comment: Understood, there's no way and it's by design. Same behavior in TFS 2017?